# How do I customize vertex label texts in tree plot correctly?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

By the following code

`TreeGraph[{1, 2, 3}, {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3}, VertexLabels -> {"a", "b", "b"}]`

I get [image].

This is incorrect. I need "a" to label the vertex at the top and "b" to label vertexes at the second level. Anyone know the correct code? Thank you!

Comment: Try it with this: VertexLabels -> {1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 3 -> "b"} (Look under the details for the [VertexLabels](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexLabels.html) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I think the minimal solution to your specific question is:

```
TreeGraph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3}, VertexLabels -> {1 -> "a", "b"}]
```

or

```
Graph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3}, VertexLabels -> {1 -> "a", "b"}]
```